# Почему без второго 'return' программа не работает?

Tags: java

Имеется задача, в рамках которой требуется из одной строки (base) удалить все подстроки (remove) без учета регистра. Задача была решена следующим образом:

```
public String withoutString(String base, String remove) {
  String result = "";

  for (int i = 0; i < (base.length()-remove.length()+1); i++)
    if (!base.substring(i, i+remove.length()).toLowerCase().equals(remove.toLowerCase()))
      result += base.substring(i, i+1);
    else if (i+remove.length() < base.length())
      i += remove.length()-1;
    else
      return result;

  for (int j = base.length()-remove.length()+1; j < base.length(); j++)
    result += base.substring(j, j+1);

  return result;
}
```

Без конструкции

```
else
  return result;
```

программа проходит все проверки, кроме случая "Hi HoHo","Ho" (вывод: "Hi o").

**Вопрос**: почему здесь необходим оператор `return` (второй, по сути), и тот же оператор `break` тут не подойдет?

Благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что у вас в цикле:

```
for (int j = base.length()-remove.length()+1; j < base.length(); j++)
  result += base.substring(j, j+1);
```

совершается ненужное добавление к строке `result` последней ненужной буквы `o`, а дописав:

```
else
  return result;
```

вы сразу выходите из функции, не дойдя до этого дописывания последней буквы.

---

Ваш алгоритм:

1. Если с `i`-го индекса строка не равняется второй, то всё ок, бежим дальше
2. Если равняется, то перепрыгиваем этот участок, чтобы его не записывать в `result` при условии, что мы ещё не дошли до конца строки
3. Если равняется, и при этом после этого уже достигнем конца строки после очередного перепрыгивая, то выходим (логично)
4. Записываем последние символы, которые цикл перепрыгнул из-за условия

Всё верно, поэтому если убрать 3-й шаг, то допишет ненужные символы

Comment: Согласен, но тогда другие проверки не будут пройдены. Собственно, сама задача: https://goo.gl/CrnF9q

Comment: @Dmitry08 поправил ответ, посмотрите

Comment: Да, похоже полностью с этим разобрался. Благодарю.

Answer (score 2):

А вы скобки раставьте (очень хорошая практика, кастати, тем более в таких случаях) и понятней станет:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (base.length()-remove.length()+1); i++) 
{
    if (!base.substring(i, i+remove.length()).toLowerCase().equals(remove.toLowerCase())) 
    {
      result += base.substring(i, i+1);
    }
    else if (i+remove.length() < base.length()) 
    {
      i += remove.length()-1;
    }
    else 
    {
      /* куда выкинет break в этом месте? */
      return result;
    }
}

/* правильно, вот в эту точку, и будут совершаться лишние действия */
for (int j = base.length()-remove.length()+1; j < base.length(); j++) 
{
    result += base.substring(j, j+1);
}

return result;
```

Comment: Благодарю, согласен про `break`, но так и не понял зачем все же второй `return`?

Comment: @Dmitry08, если вы согласны про `break`, то это автоматически означает, что поняли  зачем вместо него стоит `return`...

Comment: @Dmitry08, на самом деле return нужен тут только потому, что нужно вернуть String - во чтобы это не стало. return вернет функции указанный тип, а break или continue - работают иначе и только с конкретным циклом или уровнем вложенности.

Comment: @PinkTux @And Да, полностью согласен с ролью второго `return`. Благодарю.